# PHP RAD Framework for .net developer

Tags: c#, php, ruby-on-rails-3, codeigniter, yii

I am .net developer, worked in asp.net MVC.

Now i want develop a web application in PHP. So which framework i should select or i should go for Ruby On Rails.

I want framework that provide MVC architecture and also provides plugins.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP OR http://www.phpframeworks.com/ OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Yii framework!

http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/

Yii comes with rich features: MVC, DAO/ActiveRecord, I18N/L10N, caching, authentication and role-based access control, scaffolding, testing, etc. It can reduce your development time significantly.

Yii helps you develop clean and reusable code. It follows the MVC pattern, ensuring a clear separation of logic and presentation.

Yii is nice, young, well-documented and easy to use. You will like it very much. It will be easy to use it for those who knows how to use ASP MVC framework.